# What is a 802.11ac adapter?

Tags: router, wireless-router, 802.11ac

I'm using the WRT 1900 ac router to get 802.11 ac, but I'm not able to get the ac. I make a lot of things that they suggest on the web, but I'm still with 802.11n. According to Linksys :

> What is 802.11ac and what kinds of speed does it support?  Answer :
>   The 802.11ac technology works on the 5 GHz band.  The Linksys
>   WRT1900AC can have a speed of up to 1300 Mbps wirelessly when matched
>   with an **802.11ac adapter** and when the Channel Width on the router
>   is set to Auto.

What is this 802.11ac adapter? Is it really necessary?

I bought this second-hand router, but I think I lack a tool that is originally in the box.

Comment: Check out this succinct explanation on the difference on reddit : https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/3des0n/eli5wifi_speeds/

Comment: @Carrein Could you explain your point? I don't think this going to answer my question.

Comment: Wireless 'ac' is a standard, like 'n' and 'g'. Broadly speaking, they support different speeds, with 'ac' being the quickest. If you want 'ac' speeds, your device connected to the router needs to support 'ac', hence the adapter.

Comment: Most modern device support 'ac' out of the box, or an adapter is required to get the 'ac' functionality. Also remember, that while 'ac' does allow for faster speeds, you bandwidth is still limited by what your provider sets. If you have a 25mbps broadband plan, an 'ac' router/adapter will not magically boost your speeds past 25mbps.

Comment: @Carrein Ok, I understand... I have a MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012). How could I know that my computer support ac? If it not support ac, how could I adapt my computer?

Comment: The adapter they are referring to is the network card in your PC / Laptop / Phone.  This must be AC compatible to get AC speeds.  Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: @Carrein I think the 802.11 ac technology is more recent than 2012, so probably my Mac doesn't support 802.11 ac.

Comment: @Sandra Ross - the adapter in your model of laptop is running on the 802.11n standard. You will need to obtain an external wireless adapter capable of 802.11ac.

Comment: @n8te What do you suggest? Is it possible to get something I could fix or change in the computer? I prefer to don't get something like a usb key, so on.

Comment: Sorry but I don't have any specific hardware recommendations but there are plenty of them out there that will do the job.

Comment: @n8te Do you know which piece in the Mac must I change?

Comment: I was going to suggest a USB wireless adapter as the way to go, but I guess you're opposed to that option. I think that's going to be your only option, though. Unless someone wants to correct me on that.

Comment: Why is it the only option? What, in my computer, allow me to use the 802.11n? Why don't could we change that device?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46274/discussion-between-n8te-and-sandra-ross).

Comment: short answer, you don't. replacing a wifi nic in a macbook is non-trivial, and voids the manufacturer warranty. here are the steps involved: https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Core+Duo+AirPort+Card+Replacement/287 and of course, you will have to find a compatible replacement.

Comment: @FrankThomas I have no longer manufacturer warranty, so I'll probably change my old  Airport Extreme adapter for a new one.

Answer (score 2):

802.11 is the technical standard for wireless networking that's commonly marketed as "Wi-Fi".

802.11ac is the latest, fastest form of Wi-Fi (as of this writing).

An 802.11ac adapter is a Wi-Fi "card" (a small circuit board module with some Wi-Fi chips on it) that lets your computer speak 802.11ac. Your 2012 MacBook's built-in 802.11 adapter only does 802.11n. The 2013 model year MacBooks added 802.11ac.

The built-in Wi-Fi cards in Macs are very specialized and not user serviceable. You can't just hope to find an after-market 802.11ac upgrade card that you can use to replace your Mac's built-in card.

So to add 802.11ac support to your MacBook, you would need to buy an external 802.11ac Wi-Fi USB adapter. It's a device about the size of a large USB flash drive, often with a small antenna sticking up, that plugs into one of your USB ports and acts as an additional Wi-Fi device for your computer. You would turn off your computer's built-in Wi-Fi device and use the external device to do your wireless networking.

Please beware that most 802.11ac Wi-Fi USB adapters are designed for the Windows market, and may not come with Mac drivers (that is, they may not work with your Mac when you're running macOS; only if you're running Windows via Boot Camp). So be careful to buy a model that comes with Mac drivers and has good reviews from Mac-specific websites that do product reviews.

Answer (score 0):

A 802.11ac "adapter" is just a fancy way of saying, "A device compatible with 802.11ac." Honestly, most devices can do fine.